# show date in wishlist magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show **date** in the which the item added to the wishlist in magento 1.9.

I found this block in xml for price

```
   <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="wishlist/item/column/price.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                        <title>Price</title>
                    </action>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                </block>
```

I want to display date after the price in wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in three simple steps :

1. Add this xml in your `local.xml`

   ```
   <wishlist_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="customer.wishlist.items">
           <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.date" after="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="wishlist/item/date.phtml">
                   <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                       <title>Date</title>
                   </action>
                   <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
           </block>
    </reference>
   ```
2. Add `date.phtml` file in template folder `wishlist/item/date.phtml`
3. Paste this code in `date.phtml` file

   ```
   $item = $this->getItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();
   $options = $this->getChild('customer.wishlist.item.options')
   ->setItem($item)
   ->getConfiguredOptions();
   ?>
   <div class="cart-cell">    
         <?php echo $this->getItem()->getAddedAt();?>
       </div>
   ```

And you have done.